# How to add voiceover to a video programmatically in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How do I add voiceover commentary to a dialog video programmatically with Objective-C iOS ? I tried to use AVMutableComposition class to merge recording audio to dialog video but seem it mix them together (the video background sound totally lost after merged), can't make voiceover with it.

Anybody can help ?

here is the code I used:

```
-(void)mergeAudio:(NSString *)audioPath toVideo:(NSString *)videoPath
{
    AVURLAsset* videoAsset;
    AVURLAsset* audioAsset;

    AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

    NSURL *audio_url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioPath];
    audioAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:audio_url options:nil];
    CMTimeRange audio_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, audioAsset.duration);

    AVMutableCompositionTrack *b_compositionAudioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    [b_compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:audio_timeRange ofTrack:[[audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

    NSURL *video_url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath];
    videoAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:video_url options:nil];
    CMTimeRange video_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,audioAsset.duration);

    AVMutableCompositionTrack *a_compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    [a_compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:video_timeRange ofTrack:[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

    NSArray *dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *outputFilePath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"dub.mov"]];
    NSURL *outputFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:outputFilePath];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:outputFilePath]){
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:outputFilePath error:nil];
    }
    AVAssetExportSession* _assetExport = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
    _assetExport.outputFileType = @"com.apple.quicktime-movie";
    _assetExport.outputURL = outputFileUrl;

    [_assetExport exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:
            ^(void ) {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    // Do export finish stuff
            });
    }];
}
```

Comment: " I tried to use AVMutableComposition class to merge recording audio to dialog video but seem it mix them together (the video background sound totally lost after merged)" Then you did it wrong, because AVMutableVideoComposition is exactly how you do this, and it does not lose the video background sound if you remember to _use_ the video background sound. Show your code if you want specific help.

Comment: @matt I updated the code, I capture a video using iphone camera, then merge that video with  mp3 song, the result is a new video file with the mp3 song without origin video sound, can you tell me what was wrong ?

Comment: Yes I most certainly can. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's exactly as I suggested in my comment. You create two tracks in your composition: the voiceover audio track (fetched from the file at `audioPath`) and the video track from your video (fetched from the file at `videoPath`).

But you forgot to fetch the *audio* track from your video! Hence, it is not present in the final composition.

Comment: I extract audio from video file then mix both audio files with video and it worked, but it does mean that the sound of video was lost when mix only video & first audio file, therefore I need to extract audio from video and merge them together, do you have another better way ? and still my question is why the sound of video lost ?

Comment: The sound of the video is not "lost". It was never there! You fetched the video track but you didn't fetch the audio track. — You don't need to merge anything. You will have two audio tracks: the voiceover track, and the audio track taken from the video. See the discussion in my book: I do exactly what you are trying to do (add a voiceover track to a video): http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch28.html#_introduction_to_av_foundation_video

Comment: Yes matt, as you said "..and the audio track taken from the video" which is the part need extract from video then compose them to voiceover track right ?

Comment: You don't need to compose them. Look at the code I pointed you to. You will have three tracks: one video, two audio. Please don't make me repeat myself over and over.

Comment: well you are right, the sound is not lost. I completely solve it, thanks for your help! btw, it's good book @matt